# x-data reset on every refresh in alpinejs with tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js, phoenix-live-view

tailwindcss and phoenix liveview.
My code look like this

```
<div x-data="{isExpaned: false}">
  <button @click="isExpanded = !isExpaned">Parent menu</button>
  <div x-show="ixExpanded">Sub menu</div>
</div>

And First loaded page, even though isExpanded value is false, it shows sub menu.
and refresh the page also shows submenu.
And I checked that x-data="{isExpanded: false}"
why is it happened?
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to tailwindcss nor alpinejs
It relates to Phoenix liveview setup
I need to add this code to work with alpinejs and liveview together in app.js file

```
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket('/live', Socket, {
  dom: {
    onBeforeElUpdated(from, to) {
      if (from.__x) {
        window.Alpine.clone(from.__x, to)
      }
    }
  },
  params: {
    _csrf_token: csrfToken
  },
  hooks: Hooks
})
```